# HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread 3

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

If I add the below snippet in DataSourceContext.xml, I don't get any error and the application works as expected.

```
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.my.portal.user.UserDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

I would like my  scan packages and register beans without above snippet in DataSourceContext.xml.

How can I achieve this?

Here are my complete code:

**Web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**DataSourceContext.xml**

```
<!-- Data Source Setup -->
<bean id="myDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Sessionfactory Bean Definition -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDS"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.my.portal.user.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Setup -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")  
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="UserId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int UserId;
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    public int getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "UserId="+UserId+", FirstName="+FirstName+", LastName="+LastName;
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public UserController(UserService userService){
    this.userService = userService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String user(Locale locale, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("getUser",userService.getUser());
    return "user";

}
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserDAO {

    public List<User> getUser();

}
```

**UserDAOImpl.java**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl  implements UserDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    private Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> getUser() {
        List<User> userList = currentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
        return userList;
    }

}
```

**userService.java**

```
@Service
public interface UserService {

    public String getMessage();
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return "User Registration Page";
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> getUser(){
        logger.info("getUser()");
        return this.userDAO.getUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `@Transactional` annotation on the interface AND the impl? (Same goes for the UserServiceImpl, you have the annotation on the class and on the method getUser())

Comment: Only the service should be transactional not the dao. If you are using scanning make sure you aren't scanning for the components twice, also the component needs to be in the same context as the `<tx:annotation-driven />` else transactions won't work.

Comment: I have removed the `@Transactional` from UserServiceImpl and UserDAO. If I remove the `@Transactional` from UserDAOImpl, I am getting the same exception, even with the snippet that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I have made the service transaction, applying `@Transactional` to UserServiceImpl, but still getting the same error. I am scanning components only once.

Comment: Now I have `@Transactional` only in UserServiceImpl.java as suggested by @M.Denium but still getting the same error.

Comment: I doubt that you are scanning only once and if you are scanning make sure that that is in the same context as the `<tx:annotation-driven />` is in. I suspect the ` <tx:annotation-driven />` is in the context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and that your component-scanning is done in the `DispatcherServlet`. AOP will only work in the same context as it is configured in so AOP configured in the `ContextLoaderListener` doesn't influence the `DispatcherServlet` loaded beans and vice-versa.

Comment: I had two contexts. In the first context, I kept scanning, view resolver, and tiles configurer. The second context is DataSourceContext.xml that I posted here. As per @M. Deinum suggestion, When I combined the two contexts into one and removed the snippet that troubled me, I didn't get any error and the application works as expected.

Comment: Now, I would like to separate the configurations related to datasource/hibernate into another context. How can I do that?